# delete all rows from sql in android studio

Tags: android

my app should delete a specific row in the sql database by this method

```
 public void delete(int id){
    open();
    sqLiteDatabase.delete("item","id = "+id,null);
    close();
}
```

and it should also delete all rows if the user want that by this method

```
public void deleteAll(){
    cursor=sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select * from item",null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    i=1;
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        sqLiteDatabase.delete("item","id = "+i,null);
        i++;
        System.out.println(i);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
}
```

when the user use deleteAll() alone it is work but when he use it after using delete() it delete all rows before the deleted one using delete()

is the problem in deleteAll() method ? and how to fix it?

Comment: You might have concurrency issue (There's not enough information to know). But why not just use the sqlite API to delete all? (e.g. `sqLiteDatabase.delete("item", null ,null)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `delete()` function only deletes rows with the given `id`. If you want to delete all rows, then just do

```
sqLiteDatabase.delete("item", null ,null);
```

There is no reason to write your own loop especially since you never use the `Cursor` anyway.

Additionally, you should never use string concatenation for the "where" clause in a SQL statement. Instead use `"id = ?"` and provide a `String[]` with the values:

```
db.delete("image","id= ?", new String[] {id});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to delete a particular column with an id:

```
 SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
 db.delete("image","id= ?", new String[] {id});
 Toast.makeText(context,"Delete successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Hope this will work for you